# Codeigniter 2.2 pagination not showing

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

Try for hour but not working. I can manually switching the /welcome/index/1 or 2 or 3 in the URL. Just the damn pagination  < 1 2 3 4 > not showing !

My controller

```
        $offset = $this->uri->segment(3,0);

    $query = $this->db->query(
        'SELECT p.id AS pid,
                p.url, 
                p.created_time,
                t.name,
                t.num_photo,
                t.id AS tid
        FROM photos p
        LEFT JOIN tag_maps AS tm ON p.id = tm.photo_id
        LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON t.id = tm.tag_id
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT MAX(created_time) maxDate, t.id
            FROM photos p
            LEFT JOIN tag_maps AS tm ON p.id = tm.photo_id
            LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON t.id = tm.tag_id
            GROUP BY t.id
        ) AS d
        ON p.created_time = d.maxDate
        AND t.id = d.id
        ORDER BY p.created_time LIMIT ' . $offset . ',2'
    );
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/example/welcome/index';
    $config['total_rows'] = $query->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $config['num_links'] = 20;
```

Then in my html

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is lied on this

```
$config['total_rows'] = $query->num_rows();
```

You can't use the `$query->num_rows();`, as this is always return 2 rows.
You should have another query to get the total rows for the actual query,
which should be a `SELECT COUNT(*)`